# Create a long disjunction using the C++ api of Z3?

Tags: c++, z3

What would be the preferred way to create a long disjunction with a variable number of disjuncts?

My guess is that something like this should be possible using the `expr_vector` to first dynamically `push_back` all of the disjuncts, and then somehow use `Z3_mk_or` to build my disjunction.

But how can I get the array of `Z3_ast`'s from the `expr_vector` to pass as the third argument to `Z3_mk_or`?

Btw, is there any efficiency penalty if one creates a long sequence of binary disjunctions, rather than a single long n-ary disjunction?

Comment: I'm only guessing, but this is apparently referring to Microsoft Research's [Z3 project](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Z3 C++ API does not support the creation of an n-ary disjunction from an `expr_vector` object.
I agree this is an useful feature, and I will add it in the next Z3 release.
You can simulate this feature using the following piece of code. The following code is not perfect since it creates a "copy" of expr_vector, but it can be used as a temporary workaround. As I said above, the next version will have builtin support for this kind of operation, and the copy will be avoided.

```
#include<vector>
#include<z3++.h>
using namespace z3;

expr mk_or(expr_vector args) {
    std::vector<Z3_ast> array;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < args.size(); i++) 
        array.push_back(args[i]);
    return to_expr(args.ctx(), Z3_mk_or(args.ctx(), array.size(), &(array[0])));
}

int main() {
    context      c;
    expr_vector  args(c);

    args.push_back(c.bool_const("p"));
    args.push_back(c.bool_const("q"));
    args.push_back(c.bool_const("r"));

    std::cout << mk_or(args) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Regarding your second question, there is *no* significant performance penalty if one creates a long sequence of binary disjunctions instead of a single n-ary one.
Internally, Z3 can convert between the binary and n-ary formats very efficiently.

Comment: Thanks, this is more or less the workaround that I had already coded. I'll have a look at future releases when built in support for this is provided.